# Como fazer um filrador no laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Olá, venho tentando fazer um form que recebe um cpf e se esse cpf constar no banco de dados ele retorna todos os dados ligados a esse cpf (nome, cargo, código etc) logo ao lado do form, na mesma view. Porém estou tendo muita dificuldades em fazer. Segue abaixo os códigos:

Controller:

```
class SolicitanteController extends Controller
{   
    #Tela de Inicio
    public  function inicio(){

        $resultado = Servidor::all();
        return view('usuarios/solicitantes/inicio');

    }

    public function pegarServidor(Request $request){

        $resultado = Servidor::all();
        if($request->has('cpf')){

            $resultado = $request->get('cpf');

            return view('usuarios/solicitantes/inicio', ['resultado' => $resultado]);
        }


        return Redirect::to('usuarios/solicitantes/historico');

    }
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    @if(Session::has("msg_sucesso"))
                            <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ Session::get('msg_sucesso')}} </div>
                        @endif

    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <section id="secao_servidor">
                        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET', 'url' => 'usuarios/solicitantes/pegarServidor']) !!}

                            {!! Form::label('cpf', 'CPF: ') !!}
                            {!! Form::input('text', 'cpf', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus']) !!}
                            <br>
                            {!! Form::submit('Confirmar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </section>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <section id="secao_dadosServidor">
                        {!! Form::model('$resultado', ['method'=>'PATH', 'url' => 'usuarios/solicitantes/adicionarServidor]) !!}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <ul>

                                <li>{!! Form::input('text', 'nome',$resultado->nome, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus']) !!} </li>

                                <li>Função: </li>
                                <li>Nº Banco:</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Cargo: </li>
                                <li>Beneficiario: </li>
                                <li>Agência: </li>
                                <li>Conta: </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        </div>

                    </section>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Aqui na view fiz dois form, um para cada pegar o cpf e outro para exibir os campos. Coloquei apenas um input para testar. Quero carregar os dados automáticamente em inputs pq vou reutiliza-los.

Comment: você faz uma pesquisa pelo CPF e quer que apareça no form abaixo?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Mostrando todos os dados do usuário que possui esse cpf.

Comment: `Servidor::all()` é aonde está os dados?

Comment: Sim. Acredito que tenha usado corretamente kkk

Comment: Não exatamente, se é ai a camada que traz os dados do CPF você está fazendo errado é dentro do `If` faz um where e sobe os valores para cima!

Comment: Desculpas, mas quando você fala "subir os dados", o que significa?

Comment: Você está aprendendo `Laravel`?

Comment: Sim. Estou há algumas semanas com ele.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47950/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-ramones).